# Workaround for Firebase synchronicity in Swift 3 not working

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to force some functions to finish getting info from Firebase before using it. While I have been reading up on dispatch groups and completion handling, I don't understand why just doing the below doesn't work:

```
while (self.expectedPointCount == -1) {
    self.ref?.child("Users").child(self.userID!).child("presetRouteCoordinateCount").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:{
            snapshot in
            self.expectedPointCount = snapshot.value as! Int //always zero or greater

    })
        while(self.expectedPointCount == -1){}
}
```

This runs forever.

Inserting print statements in the while loop and in the Firebase snapshot routine suggest that it's actually never entering the Firebase snapshot routine. It does enter the routine when it's not in a while loop, however.

It looks like I'm going to have to do it the hard way, but I just don't understand why.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This will infinite loop. Although the Firebase call is executed asynchronously on a different thread, it never gets a chance to start as you never leave the infinite while loop on the thread you are calling from.